# Why doesn't this print anything on the screen?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    int index;
    int t;
    int d;
    int sum;
};

A arr[1000];

bool comp (const A &a, const A &b)
{
    if (a.sum < b.sum)
        return true;
    else if (a.sum == b.sum && a.index < b.index)
        return true;
    return false;
}
int main (void)
{
    int n,foo,bar,i;
    i = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while ( n != 0 )
    {
        cin>>foo>>bar;
        arr[i].index = i+1;
        arr[i].t = foo;
        arr[i].d = bar;
        arr[i].sum = arr[i].t+arr[i].d;
        n--;
        i++;
    }
    sort(arr,arr+n,comp);
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        cout<<arr[j].index;
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, I made this program which accepts values from users, and then sorts them on the basis of a specific condition. However, when I try to print the values of the array, it doesn't print it. I don't know why. Please help. Thanks!

PS: I even tried to print the value of the array without use of comparator function, but still it doesn't print.

Edit: Got my error, as mentioned by some amazing people in the comments. However, on inputting the values as,

```
5
8 1
4 2
5 6
3 1
4 3
```

It should return the answer as `4 2 5 1 3` but instead it returns `1 2 3 4 5`. Basically, it sorts according to the sum of the 2 elements in each row and prints the index. What might be the problem?

Comment: try adding `cout<<endl;` instead of `"\n"` - it will flush the output.

Comment: `while ( n != 0 )` loops until `n==0`, so the last `for` loop is never entered.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say @Matt :)

Comment: @Matt, thanks for pointing out the silly error. My bad. But, can you please look at the comparator function too as to what might be the error? Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `comp` returns if both the conditions are false?

Comment: Nothing, but it should return false, however, even after adding the return false statement, it doesn't sort.

Comment: I'm not sure what was your fix regarding n becoming 0 after the while loop. That might be related - you use it later on in the sort call, effectively giving it an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sorting because you are modifying the value of `n` in the `while` loop.

So, when `n = 0` after the loop ends, there is nothing to sort (or to print later for that matter):

```
sort( arr, arr + n, comp);
```

is equivalent to

```
sort( arr, arr + 0, comp);
```

Easiest approach would be to use a `for` loop:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; ++i )
{
    ....
}
```

This way, `n` remains unchanged.